# System of parametric inequalities

Tags: inequality, parametric

I'm still struggling with the parametric inequalities.I'm doing some systems of parametric inequalities, but I can not understand how to proceed.This is the system:

$x-2a<1+a$

$\frac x2 -2a<2x-(a-3)$

$\frac 13 -x<a$ per $a>0$

These are the solutions I've found:

$x<3a+1$

$x>{-2a-6\over 3}$

$x>{-3a+1\over 3}$

But now I do not know how to proceed. I thought I could compare the solutions like:

$3a+1>{-2a-6\over 3}>{-3a+1\over 3}$

If you could help me, I'd be really grateful. 
And if it's not too much trouble, if you could recommend some books or a detailed explanation on the literal inequalities and elementary algebra.

Comment: @lolwut Thank you.Could you explain why we don't worry about the first outcome, $x<3a+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy when you have two inequalities, like $x>\frac{6-2a}3$ and $x>\frac{1-3a}3$, where the signs are the same (i.e. the both say $x>\text{expression}$) is to compare the things $x$ is compared to. So we will determine whether $\frac{-6-2a}3>\frac{1-3a}3$ or not.

For that inequality, one should solve the corresponding equation $\frac{-6-2a}3=\frac{1-3a}3$. Its solution is $a=7$. Now, one can solve the inequality. Pick a test value $a=0$, and plug it in both sides. On the left hand side it is $-2$ and on the right, $1/3$. Thus $\frac{-6-2a}3<\frac{1-3a}3$ holds for all $a<7$, while $\frac{-6-2a}3>\frac{1-3a}3$ holds for $a>7$.

Therefore, the assertion that $x$ is greater than both $\frac{-6-2a}3$ and $\frac{1-3a}3$ is the same as saying $x>\frac{1-3a}3$ when $a\le 7$ and $x>\frac{-6-2a}3$ when $a\ge7$.

Since we only have one inequality of the form $\text{expression}>x$, we do not have to do anything else, as the system of inequalities now splits into two pieces: $$1+3a > x >\frac{1-3a}3\text{ if }a\le7\qquad1+3a>x>\frac{-6-2a}3 \text{ if }a\ge7$$ which, without any further information, counts as a solution.

Comment: The solution of the inequality is $x>{-2a-6\over 3}$, I checked here:http://symbolab.com/solver/inequalities-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B2%7D-2a%3C2x-(a-3).I got $a=7$,which is the solution given by my book.The rest of the explanation is perfect but I don't understand why we do not take into account the outcome of the first inequality $x<3a+1$

Comment: You forgot a $2$ in $\frac x2-\color{red}{2}a<2x-(a-3)$.

Comment: And indeed *you* got the sign wrong, not the OP.

Comment: Mik23 & @JMCF125: Thanks. I did indeed get the sign wrong. Mik23: If you have further questions--esp. if it remains unclear why we don't have to worry about $x<3a+1$--do not hesitate to ask in the comments.

Comment: You're welcome. The sign is still wrong in the first line though (but in that case they're examples, so it doesn't really matter). So, +1 for giving a good answer.

Comment: @lolwut thank you for the explanation,it's perfect.